# RoR using a number as a database column name generates an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I'm attempting to use an hour of the day as the name of a column, and keep receiving this error:

```
/root/_____/db/migrate/20140718155649_create_mondays.rb:5: Invalid octal digit
  t.text :0900
            ^
syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
```

Is this possible, or should I try something else?

Comment: Try using `t.text '0900'` (the problem is that Ruby's symbols cannot start with a digit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ruby the symbols cannot start with number when using `:` syntax to create them. Try using a string instead of symbol as follows:

```
t.text '0900'
```

Comment: `In ruby the symbols can start only with alphabets` => That is not completely true: they cannot start with a digit but it works with `_`: `:_method` works.

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly.